# TagLib Heroku Vulcan - Binary Packaging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, taglib

I'm using taglib-ruby to extract information from songs.

I've had 3 different suggestions:

1. Contact Heroku and they can help you with your issue
2. Installing taglib by SSHing into heroku (Not sure if this is possible.)
3. Producing a binary gem where the extensions are already compiled and ship libtag.so alongside the gem.

Any other better solutions? Which solution is the best?

Update:

Trying to package Binary using Vulcan and I hit an error since TagLib is using Cmake.

```
vulcan build -v -s ./taglib-1.8beta
Packaging local directory... done
Uploading source package... done
Building with: ./configure --prefix /app/vendor/taglib-1 && make install
sh: ./configure: not found
bin/make:66:in `chdir': No such file or directory - /app/vendor/taglib-1 (Errno::ENOENT)
    from bin/make:66:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
    from bin/make:18:in `chdir'
    from bin/make:18:in `block in <main>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tmpdir.rb:83:in `mktmpdir'
    from bin/make:17:in `<main>'
```

Comment: FYI, there's open [issue](https://github.com/heroku/vulcan/issues/32) on Vulcan for `cmake` support.

Comment: I actually made that issue as well. Thanks though.

Comment: ha! I didn't notice. At least it's there for future viewers of this question.

Comment: @Jches Are there any updates for this question ? im trying to do the same but dint understand much from github issue.

Comment: @VivekSampara Unfortunately no. I'd suggest using a VPS. https://github.com/heroku/vulcan/issues/32 <-- this thread may help. It's really unfortunate that Heroku makes deployment 'appear' to be really easy.I'm still grateful for the company though...they need to update their vulcan gem functionality basically

Answer (score 1):

1. is always available, and you'll have a clear answer
2. is not possible
3. is something doable, but probably not recommended. As you don't know on which platform your code is running, you'll have to test by yourself, and Heroku could change its platform whenever they want to.

I would start with 1 and try 3.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to install taglib on heroku by creating a [custom buildpack](https://github.com/menan/heroku-buildpack-ruby.git). (Here is [how to use a custom buildpack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#using-a-custom-buildpack) if you're unsure.)